# How to create a dragging animation for a UIView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have a hidden `UIView` at the bottom of my `UIViewController`.

I would like to create an interactive animation that would show progressively my `UIView`, like if I was dragging the `UIView` from the bottom and it would follow my finger (location, speed, etc.). If I go over half way the final location of my `UIView` and release my finger, it would continue, if I don't reach this half way, it would go back hidden. Basically, the same behaviour like the control center.

The problem is I don't know where to start. Can someone point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `UIGestureRecognizer`,for example `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer`

1. keep a property

   ```
   var gestureReconginzer:UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer?
   ```
2. Then in viewDidLoad,init the `gestureReconginzer`

   ```
   gestureReconginzer = UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "catch:")
   gestureReconginzer?.edges = UIRectEdge.Bottom
   self.view.addGestureRecognizer(gestureReconginzer!)
   ```
3. When the gesture is Reconginzed

   ```
   func catchGestrue(gesture:UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer){
     switch(gesture.state){
       case .Began:
       //Set your view hidden = false
       case .Changed:
       //Change your view center 
       case .Ended:
       //Decide if your view reach half way.
       //Use  UIView.animateWithDuration to let your view return or go to right place
       default:
     }
   }
   ```

**BTY**: I do not think pull a view from bottom is a good idea.

I have a simple objective C project in [here](https://github.com/wenchenhuang/WCBlurSideMenu),if you know objective C,you may refer the gesture part.